# How can access AWS RDS by CLI / PUTTY?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS , I can access EC2 user by putty. Like this how can i connect AWS RDS by PUTTY ?

I have AWS RDS Endpoint , If i try like the below

```
mysql -h testing.cx2wamr3cbzm.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u Username -p
```

**I am getting some error like**

*ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'testing.cx2wamr3cbzm.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)*

I think there is a problem with security group.I searched more, but its difficult to understand for me.

I want to create database and assign rights ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

RDS is not available to the world by default. It's also generally a bad idea to allow access to the RDS from anywhere except from inside your VPC. I recommend you do the following:

**Create a security group that allows access to the RDS over port 3306 from your EC2 instance**

1. Visit https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#s=SecurityGroups and create a new security group.
2. Switch to the **inbound** tab and choose **MYSQL** from the dropdown.
3. Erase the 0.0.0.0/0 in the source field then click the input field. It will present you with a list of existing security groups. Choose the one that your EC2 instance belongs to.
4. Click the **apply rule changes** button

**Assign the security group to your RDS**

1. Visit https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home#dbinstances: and select your RDS instance and under the **Instance Actions** menu select **Modify**
2. Change the RDS security group to the one you just created
3. Make sure to select the **Apply immediately** option at the bottom of this page
4. Click Continue and apply the new changes. (the change can sometimes take a couple of minutes)

**SSH into your EC2 instance then run the mysql command in your question**

Comment: Yeah, but what if you don't have any other instance running besides the RDS instance? Is there not a way to ssh to the RDS instance directly?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I suggest you just spin up a micro instance and use that, They are really cheap and free if you signed up in the last 12 months

Comment: Hey in the 1st step, is it 'inbound' or 'Outbound' tab i need to select...Cause in inbound, i get blank fields...in Outbound there is a drop down for Mysql/Aurora...Or in bound, do we need to 'Add Rule' and then select 'MYSQL'

Comment: @KeeganLillo ... I found your answer to be really helpful. I did all the steps correctly as mentioned by you, now when I connect to my ec2 instance and try to use mysql command it says "mysql command not found". Can you please help with that. I am using Mobaxterm for connection.