# I can't access AWS RDS MySQL database via Putty

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a MySQL database on AWS RDS and set up everything by referring to this link: [How can access AWS RDS by CLI / PUTTY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020416/how-can-access-aws-rds-by-cli-putty)

But I couldn't access that database via Putty. It returns an error even though I tried several times.

This is the screenshot of my Putty:

[image]

And this is the MySQL database I've created and setup:

[image]

Comment: Your `RDS` is not accessible via public internet. You have `Publicly Accessibilty to No`. Check your screenshot. Also, can you describe if you have this `RDS` in `private subnet` or `public`? Are you accessing this `RDS` from inside your `VPC` or from your pc? If from your `VPC`, you need to whitelist your `EC2` ip from your `RDS` on `port 3306` and if from your home pc, you need to have your `RDS` in public subnet(bad bad idea) and accessible by whitelisting your public ip on `RDS` and you need to change `public accessibilty->yes`.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help. I learnt lots.

Comment: I modified everything but the same issue. Can you please help me with that via teamview if you can?

Comment: It's quite difficult to have it privately. It's an open forum. How can we exchange credentials?. I would ask you to present to me(and others) with more information, so that we can help solve the issue. Firstly, paste a screenshot or confirm that both `RDS` and the `EC2` are in the same `vpc`. secondly, go to your `security group` of `RDS(CANOP_MYSQL...)` and whitelist `private ip of your instance` on `port 3306` on `inbound`. I am not sure if your `EC2` is in public or private but for testing purposes whitelist `port 3306` outbound to `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: after the above steps do `telnet canop-mysql-database.cljjecv2bwhl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`. If it doesn't timeout, you have resolved your issue. Provide as many details as possible if it still doesn't work. About your instance, your security groups, your vpc. If the instances are in private or public subnet etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like connection issue.

Check Security group(s) attached to your RDS instance.
One of the Security Groups should allow access on 3306/tcp port from one of:

- Security Group of your EC2 instance
- IP address of your EC2 instance
- IP address pool of your EC2 instance subnet
- IP address pool of your VPC

Verify if any of Security Groups attached to your RDS instance allows outgoing traffic to one of:

- Security Group of your EC2 instance
- IP address of your EC2 instance
- IP address pool of your EC2 instance subnet
- IP address pool of your VPC
- 0.0.0.0/0